# Failed to execute 'share' on 'Navigator': A earlier share had not yet completed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, navigator

I just saw some users on my site experience this error

> InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'share' on 'Navigator': A earlier share had not yet completed.

This happens on this portion of the code:

```js
if(navigator.share) {
  navigator.share({
    url: 'https://www.example.com',
  });
}
```

The [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#exceptions) do not even mentions about possibility of this error.

I saw the the error is coming from Chrome browser from Windows, Android and Chrome Os. I saw that chrome on mac do not have share feature as of now. Worth to mention that the issue happens quite rarely. I tried to reproduce it, by clicking the share multiple times fast, throttling cpu and network, canceling the share and I was never able to make it throw this error.

Do anyone know how to trigger this error or saw any documentation about it?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, so looking forward to read about the reasons and the possible solution.

Comment: Can confirm, same issue on Edge 107 which makes this a chromium engine issue.

Answer (score 2):

Initially I thought this happens if you do not `try...catch` the `share()` operation and abandon the first share. This does not seem to be the case. I have now opened a [Chromium bug](https://crbug.com/1377823) to see what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to

> Do anyone know how to trigger this error [...]?

You can trigger it by:

1. Start a WebShare
2. Abandon it (click anywhere else)
3. Start the WebShare again without refreshing the page

*Tested in Edge and Chrome (MacOS)*